# HTML Image Change on Hover with Pop up text

Tags: html, image, text, popup, hover

I made this code some time ago, it does everything I could want, well, almost. I can't for the life of me figure out how to add pop up text when the user hovers over the image; then disappears when the user hovers off the image.

Here is a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dt14x2ru/) of my code, as well as it below.

```
<a href="PAGE-URL"><img src="http://www.bizreport.com/2011/02/03/android-logo-200x200.jpg" onmouseover="this.src='https://logopond.com/avatar/154827/no-bullshit.jpg'" onmouseout="this.src='http://www.bizreport.com/2011/02/03/android-logo-200x200.jpg'" /></a>
```

Comment: [This link](https://codepen.io/Navedkhan012/pen/NrdLXW) was posted in a link-only answer, which has now been deleted. I am re-posting it in case it is helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CSS Tooltip is what you should be looking for I reckon.

```css
.tooltip {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    border-bottom: 1px dotted black;
}

.tooltip .tooltiptext {
    visibility: hidden;
    width: 120px;
    background-color: black;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 6px;
    padding: 5px 0;

    /* Position the tooltip */
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
}

.tooltip:hover .tooltiptext {
    visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<div class="tooltip">
  <a href="PAGE-URL"><img src="http://www.bizreport.com/2011/02/03/android-logo-200x200.jpg" onmouseover="this.src='https://logopond.com/avatar/154827/no-bullshit.jpg'" onmouseout="this.src='http://www.bizreport.com/2011/02/03/android-logo-200x200.jpg'" /></a>
  <span class="tooltiptext">Tooltip text</span>
</div>
```